# magento2 - How to get a product's stock status enabled/disabled?

Tags: magento2, stock

I'm trying to get whether the product's stock status is instock/outofstock (Integers representing each state are fine. i don't necessarily need the "in stock"/"out of stock" strings per se).

I've tried various things to no avail.

1)

```
$inStock = $obj->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface')->getisInStock()'

// Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface :: getisInStock returns true no matter what, even for 0qty products
// summary: not useful. How do you get the real one?
```

2)

```
$inStock = $obj->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface')->verifyStock($_product->getId());

// test results for "verifyStock":
// a 0 qty product is in stock
// a 0 qty product is out of stock
// summary: fail. find correct method, with tests.
```

3)

```
$stockItemRepository = $obj->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository');
stockItem = $stockItemRepository->get($_product->getId());
$inStock = $stockItem->getIsInStock();

// Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: Stock Item with id "214" 
// summmary: is stockitem not 1to1 with proudctid?
```

---

The weird thing is, getting stock quantities works just fine.

```
$availability = (String)$obj->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface')->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
```

So why isn't getIsInStock working?

Answer (score 0):

This was one way I did it.

```
    $stockItemResource = $obj->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item');

    // grab ALL stock items (i.e. object that contains stock information)
    $stockItemSelect = $stockItemResource->getConnection()->select()->from($stockItemResource->getMainTable());
    $stockItems = $stockItemResource->getConnection()->fetchAll($stockItemSelect);


    $inStock = null;
    foreach($stockItems as $k => $item) {
        if ($item['product_id'] == $_productId) {
            $inStock = $item['is_in_stock'];
            break; // not breaking properly. 'qz' still prints
        }
    }
```

**Notes on efficiency:**

I'm sure there are another ways to target the single item specifically, instead of getting all. Either through a method, or by adjusting the query passed in somehow.

But this method is probably more efficient for large n, avoiding the n+1 query problem.

You do still end up iterating through a lot, but perhaps theta(n) of iterating through a cached PHP variable is probably lower than n+1 querying the database. Haven't tested, just a hypothesis.

The returned structure is an array of arrays, where the sub-array (which also happens to be a stock item) has the product ID and the stock status value. And because the product ID and the stock status value is on the same level of nesting, we have no choice but to iterate through each sub-array to check the product_id, choose that sub-array, and grab the stock value. In short, we can't just utilize the hashmap, since the keys of the sub-array are not product IDs.

Ultimately, the efficiency of this depends on your use case. Rarely will you grab all stock items, unless doing mass exports. So the ultimate goal is to really just stay within the configured time limit is allowed for a request to persist.